# hadoop-1.0.3 sequenceFile.Writer overwrites instead of appending images into a sequencefile

Tags: hadoop, image-processing, filesystems, hdfs, sequence

I am using hadoop 1.0.3 (I can't really upgrade right now,Thats for later. ) 
I have around 100 images in my HDFS and I am trying to combine them into a single sequencefile ( default no compression etc.. )

here's my code:

```
            FSDataInputStream  in = null;
                BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
                Text key = new Text();
                Path inpath = new Path(fs.getHomeDirectory(),"/user/hduser/input");
                Path seq_path = new Path(fs.getHomeDirectory(),"/user/hduser/output/file.seq");
                FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(inpath);
                SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
                for( FileStatus fileStatus : files){
                          inpath = fileStatus.getPath();
                try {

                            in =  fs.open(inpath);
                            byte bufffer[] = new  byte[in.available()];
                            in.read(bufffer);
                            writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs,conf,seq_path,key.getClass(),value.getClass());
                            writer.append(new Text(inpath.getName()), new BytesWritable(bufffer));



                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception MESSAGES = "+e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
```

This just goes through all the files in input/ and one by one appends them.
**HOWEVER** this just overwrites my sequence file instead of appending it , I see only the last image in sequencefile.

**NOTE** I am not closing the writer before the for loop ends , can anyone help me with this please. 
I am not sure How can I append the images?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is with the following line :

```
 writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf, seq_path, key.getClass(), value.getClass());
```

which is inside the `for`, creating a new `writer` in each pass. It replaces previous file at the path `seq_path`. Thus only last image is available.

Pull it out of the loop, and the problem should vanish.